# How to include the ToC page in page counting on mPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have a 'report' with more than 30 pages. I need to place the mPDF ToC at the 3th page *but* I need that following page to be showed as 4th page at ToC, not 3th page as mPDF does.

Now I have:

```
Page - Subject
01 - Front
02 - Notes
03 - ToC <<<< Plz, note the page number
04 - First useful topic
05 - [Other]
```

But my ToC is showed this way:

```
First Useful Topic ............... 03
[Other]........................... 04
```

The counting is clearly wrong.
I need it to be:

```
First Useful Topic ............... 04
[Other]........................... 05
```

How can I accomplish it in mPDF, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I did not know it would be so hard. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're simply inserting your TOC as follows:

```
$mpdf->TOCpagebreak();
```

You can reset the page number of 4 using

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="4" suppress="off" />');
```

right before you write the content for page 4

Comment: As soon as possible i will test your answer Alexey. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I was not being able to post on this topic anymore. My logging through google account was not working and I had no idea why not. I found a router problem, fixed now.

By the way, your solution help me so much. I will mark it as 'the solution, although I made some changes:

    <tocpagebreak resetpagenum="4" toc-odd-footer-value="-1" />

Thank you so much.